# Is $M=\{x(t)\in C_{[0,1]}:x(t)=e^{-\alpha t}\}$ pre-compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Study the pre compactness of $M=\{x(t)\in C_{[0,1]}:x(t)=e^{-\alpha t}\}$, for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

I am supposed to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem:

> **Theorem**:For a set $M$ to be pre-compact it is necessary and sufficient  this set to be equicontinuous.

So I tried to prove that $\exists \delta>0,\epsilon>0,\forall t_1,t_2\in[0,1] $

$$|t_1-t_2|<\delta\:\:\:\:\:\:\:|x(t_1)-x(t_2)|<\epsilon\:\:\:\forall x(t)\in M$$

So I shall try to prove:

$\exists \delta>0,\epsilon>0,\forall t_1,t_2\in[0,1] $

$$|t_1-t_2|<\delta\:\:\:\:\:\:\:|e^{-\alpha t_1}-e^{-\alpha t_2}|<\epsilon\:\:\:\forall x(t)\in M$$

Using Lagrange Mean Value theorem:

$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=-\alpha e^{-\alpha t}$

For $\xi\in [0,1]$

$|e^{-\alpha t_1}-e^{-\alpha t_2}|=-\alpha e^{-\alpha\xi}|t_1-t_2|\leqslant?$

**Question:**

**1)** I do not know how to proceed. How should I do it?

**2)** Is there another easier method to major $|e^{-\alpha t_1}-e^{-\alpha t_2}|$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to clarify your definitions. Because from what I see $M$ is not a set of functions and it is unusual to speak about equicontinuity in this case. What do you think ?

Comment: I do not understand also $x(t) \in C_{[0,1]}$ for me $x(t)$ is a scalar and not a function.

Comment: @Youem Why is not $M$ a set of functions? $M\subset C_{[0,1]}$. $x(t)$ is a continuous function on $C_{[0,1]}$. Have you any problem with the terminology?

Comment: If I understand the question the correct way to define of $M$ is : For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ let $$f_\alpha : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto e^{-\alpha t}$$ and $$M = \{f_\alpha : \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Comment: @Youem                 The Professor defined it exactly as I posted it. The difference may be a cultural one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is not equicontinuous. Suppose that it were, there is some $\delta>0$ such that for all $t_{1},t_{2}\in[0,1]$ with $|t_{1}-t_{2}|\leq\delta$ and $\alpha\in{\bf{R}}$, we have $|e^{-\alpha t_{1}}-e^{-\alpha t_{2}}|<1$. Now take $t_{1}=\delta$, $t_{2}=0$, we have $|e^{-\alpha\delta}-1|<1$ and hence $e^{-\alpha\delta}<2$ for all $\alpha\in{\bf{R}}$. Taking $\alpha\rightarrow-\infty$, the expression blows up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Sometimes I wonder how someone comes up with such an idea. Is there some tricks? Or is just creativity on the moment?

Comment: Actually in your answer there is already a hint why doing so. You have $\alpha e^{-\alpha t}$ which fails to be bounded for all $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

The set $M=\{t\mapsto e^{-\alpha t}\vert \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}\subset C[0,1]$ is **not** precompact. If it was, then in particular the sequence $(x_n\colon t\mapsto e^{nt})_n\subset M$ had a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$  converging to some $y\in C[0,1]$.
Evaluation at $1$ defines a continuous functional $F\colon C[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R},x\mapsto x(1)$, thus $e^{{n_k}}=F(x_{n_k})\rightarrow F(y)$ and in particular $(e^{{n_k}})_k\subset \mathbb{R}$ was bounded. This is absurd.